# Web application and API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, web

I have a web application on my domain, I just allow so IPs to connect, talk and retrieves from my app, now the problem is that another API needs to talk to my app and retrieve info, but I can't open my app to the public , also the API doesn't allow token authentication, it just wants to connect to my app from any IP, any ideas to solve this?
a third party is an option but I need another practical option

Comment: Please explain a little more about what you've tried, and what sort of solution you're looking for. As an example, are you trying to interact with a pre-made API? What programming language or framework are you using? Are you looking for a network solution that whitelists ip addresses at the network adapter?

Comment: I'm using java, not my API no, and yes its a premade API which want to talk to my application, but as I said security problems with IPs and so on

Comment: So you don't want authentication, it can be used from any ip and it cannot be public. Pick 2 out of 3 of these requirements and maybe we got something ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to answer your question from whatever I can understand, if api does not allow any token authentication , then you need to implement something which will authenticate/validate/verify the incoming requests.
Now, if you don't have any scope of changing the implementation of the existing api, then probably you need to add a layer of say API Gateway. If you are using or want to use spring boot then it provides very simple implementation of it through Netflix Zuul.
If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more details.

Comment: you have answered all i want buddy